# Conditional Expression not working in aws_security_group resource egress block terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

for resource aws_security_group , i want to add egress block to run only if ingress rules are created. Below i have applied condition for the egress block using count then tried with for_each , but I am getting error :  An argument named "count" or "for_each" is not expected here respectively. Can someone please help how can i achieve this

**code**

```
  egress {
    #for_each             = (length(split(",", var.ingress_ports_udp)) != 0 && length(split(",", var.ingress_ports_udp)) != 0) ? ["1"] : []
    from_port         = 0
    to_port           = 0
    protocol          = "-1"
    cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). It would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "mygroup" {
  name        = "mygroup"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = (condition) ? [1] : []
    content {
      from_port         = 0
      to_port           = 0
      protocol          = "-1"
      cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
}
```

Your condition looks quite odd. First off, you're checking exactly the same condition twice (`length(split(",", var.ingress_ports_udp)) != 0` appears to be duplicated), and second, `split` will never return a list of length 0 anyways (if an empty string is given, it will return a list with one element, which is itself an empty string). You can see this on the [split documentation page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/split.html), third example:

```
> split(",", "")
[
  "",
]
```

So your condition will never be `false`, no matter what the value of `var.ingress_ports_udp` is. You can use `compact(split(",", var.ingress_ports_udp))` to deal with this ([compact](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/compact.html) will remove any list elements that are empty strings).

I'd recommend passing `var.ingress_ports_udp` in as a list of numbers, instead of as a string that you split within the module. Then you can simply use `length(var.ingress_ports_udp) > 0 ? [1] : []`.